# Passing request file into flex application with flashvar

Tags: apache-flex, flashvars

I am trying to get a xml file with data into Flex application. There are a lot of examples online passing parameter into flex I found very helpful. However, it doesn't really work in my case.

here is my code in HTML:

```
var flashvars = {};
flashvars.storageStatsXML = "stats.xml";
var params = {};
swfobject.embedSWF("mySWF.swf", "mySWF", "1000", "500", "10.0.0", "js/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params);
```

here is the code in mxml:

```
[Bindable]
public var storageStats:XML;

protected function start(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    storageStats = Application.application.parameters.storageStatsXML;
}
```

And then the XML file got parsed in the application.

I think there is something not right about the code, any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Application.application.parameters.storageStatsXML` property is not the XML data you are expecting, it is a `String` containing the text `"stats.xml"`.

In the same way that the file path "c:\temp\info.txt" (or "/temp/info.txt") isn't the file itself, it just tells you how to find the file on disk.

You will need to use a [URLRequest](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html) to load the XML file specified by the `storageStatsXML` property.

Have a look at the Actionscript documentation and here on StackOverflow for examples on how to load external data.

Comment: if I am using the URLRequest, will the file be taken in during run-time? I tried to use the URLRequest, but it didn't work. I am following the instruction from here: http://www.kirupa.com/developer/flashcs3/using_xml_as3_pg2.htm  it didn't work.